# Grouping by with multipolygon geometry with sf (using R)

Tags: r, r-sf

I have a custom shapefile I put together. It works fine when I plot it all at once. But I'd like to group by certain variables to plot specific shaped regions. For example:

```
+-------------+--------+-------+
|   county    | region | sales |
+-------------+--------+-------+
| washoe      |      1 |     5 |
| carson city |      1 |    10 |
| clark       |      2 |    15 |
| harmon      |      2 |    20 |
+-------------+--------+-------+
```

If I run:

```
leaflet() %>% addTiles %>% addPolygons(data=df)
```

That will plot four separate polygons based on where those four are located.

But let's say I wanted to create polygons based on regions. So theoretically, the output would contain just two Polygons. One that is the combined shape of montgomery and stevens, and another combining moses and harmon county, and I also want to sum up the total sales.

```
x <- df %>% group_by(region) %>% summarise(totals=sum(ones))
```

It will give me this error:

```
Error in CPL_geos_union(st_geometry(x), by_feature) : 
  Evaluation error: TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid: Ring Self-intersection at or near point -119.97497995771261 39.521600907266631 at -119.97497995771261 39.521600907266631
```

In terms of information on the geometry variable:

```
df$geometry

Geometry set for 2106 features 
geometry type:  GEOMETRY
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -115.8968 ymin: 35.00184 xmax: -114.0428 ymax: 36.85366
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

Do I need to convert it to something else?

Comment: I can't duplicate the geos error using the code in the question with the data you've linked in a comment below (please edit your Q and link to the data in the question). So either this is a problem only with a particular geos version or that's not the data for `df` in the question. For one thing, `df` must have a column called `ones` for that to work. So what's really going on? Also is a dupe of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345011/grouping-by-with-multipolygon-geometry-with-sf-using-r

Answer (score 11):

Edit with OP's [data](https://github.com/gooponyagrinch/custom_shape):

```
shp <- st_read("file/path/sample_shape.shp")

shp_union <- shp %>% 
  mutate(turf = as.character(turf),
         turf = ifelse(is.na(turf), "NA", turf)) %>% 
  group_by(turf) %>% 
  summarize(geometry = st_union(geometry),
            total_sales = sum(sales))
```

Original geometries

```
ggplot() + geom_sf(data = shp, aes(fill = sales))
```

[image]

New geometries

```
ggplot() + geom_sf(data = shp_union, aes(fill = total_sales))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it still is not working my shapefile. What exactly is the point of creating the `group` component? Do I need to do that or was it just custom for your example?

Comment: That was just an arbitrary group I added to the `nc` data built into the `sf` package, since I don't have your data.  Could you post a snippet of your data?

Comment: So the data I used above was fake data. Here is a link to the real data. It's the same principle, except instead of county-region-sales it's region-turf-sales

https://github.com/gooponyagrinch/custom_shape

Comment: Oh, one more thing. Once you've read the file, add in:

`testdata$areas <- 1:2106`

You'll notice there's a total of 2106 rows. Those are the polygons it reads initially, you'll notice that on the map when you first run it

Comment: see my updated answer.  I'm not familiar with leaflet syntax, so I produced the maps in ggplot.  Does that work for you?

Comment: What's the purpose of `geometry = st_union(geometry)`?

Comment: it combines the geometries by group. Say you had polygons for every country. If you grouped them by continent and then did `st_union()`, you'd get 6 polygons, one for each inhabited continent.