# Computing the surface area of a variable in a shapefile in r

Tags: r, geometry, shapefile, area

My shapefile represent a continent. It has many polygons (because of several layers).

I would like to compute the surface area/squarekm for different variables and have the results in a column i.e:

Total squarekm per country (NAME variable): It would give me the square km of each country polygons.
Total squarekm per AEZ (AEZ variable): It would give me the square km of each AEZ zone

etc.

I did it in Arcmap but can't figure out how to have the same results in R.

I tried with Areapolygons but it does not work.

`> dput(PRIO[2:6,9,12:14, c(1,2)]) structure(list(NAME = c("Mauritania", "Mauritania", "Mauritania",  "Mauritania", "Mauritania"), geometry = structure(list(structure(list( list(structure(c(-8.15539750263898, -8.5, -8.5, -8.20444499999996, -8.15539750263898, 27, 27, 27.1964674367602, 27.0274960000002,  27), .Dim = c(5L, 2L)))), class = c("XY", "MULTIPOLYGON",  "sfg")), structure(list(list(structure(c(-8.5, -8.66722299999986,  -8.66722299999986, -8.66722299999986, -8.66717809129804, -8.5,  -8.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.8330540000001, 26.9663889999999, 27, 27,  26.5), .Dim = c(7L, 2L)))), class = c("XY", "MULTIPOLYGON", "sfg" )), structure(list(list(structure(c(-8, -8, -8.5, -8.5, -8.15539750263898,  -8.13111099999998, -8, 26.9105346374803, 26.5, 26.5, 27, 27,  26.9863850000001, 26.9105346374803), .Dim = c(7L, 2L)))), class = c("XY",  "MULTIPOLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(list(structure(c(-7.50000000000003,  -7.50000000000003, -8, -8, -7.71194499999996, -7.69361099999992,  -7.50000000000003, 26.6209884313231, 26.5, 26.5, 26.9105346374803,  26.7438890000001, 26.7341649999999, 26.6209884313231), .Dim = c(7L,  2L)))), class = c("XY", "MULTIPOLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list( list(structure(c(-7.29302525734133, -7.50000000000003, -7.50000000000003,  -7.29302525734133, 26.5, 26.5, 26.6209884313231, 26.5), .Dim = c(4L,  2L)))), class = c("XY", "MULTIPOLYGON", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_MULTIPOLYGON",  "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -8.66722299999986,  ymin = 26.5, xmax = -7.29302525734133, ymax = 27.1964674367602 ), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "WGS 84", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"latitude\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"longitude\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c(NA,  -5L), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(NAME = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant",  "aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"), class = c("sf",  "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your multipolygon in R, make sure it has an appropriate coordinate system, then use `st_area()`, which returns the area of each polygon (row) in your multipolygon.

```
library(sf)

# Load multipolygon
nc = st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

# Check coordinate system
st_crs(nc)
#> Coordinate Reference System:
#>   User input: NAD27 
#>   wkt:
#> GEOGCRS["NAD27",
#>     DATUM["North American Datum 1927",
#>         ELLIPSOID["Clarke 1866",6378206.4,294.978698213898,
#>             LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
#>     PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
#>         ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
#>     CS[ellipsoidal,2],
#>         AXIS["latitude",north,
#>             ORDER[1],
#>             ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
#>         AXIS["longitude",east,
#>             ORDER[2],
#>             ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
#>     ID["EPSG",4267]]

plot(nc$geometry)
```

[image: nc]

```
nrow(nc)
#> [1] 100

st_area(nc)
#> Units: [m^2]
#>   [1] 1137107793  610916077 1423145355  694378925 1520366979  967504822
#>   [7]  615794941  903423919 1179065710 1232475139 1136017416 1524295167
#>  [13] 1426763054 1085709751  718024778 1893655681  524303669 1986581059
#>  [19]  812132036  626215554  439637846  640597398  863142124 1276325061
#>  [25] 1083947009 1697657775 1109799786 1800353048 1036247721  770426970
#>  [31] 1422972995  585145178 1311460371 1224942117  800163805 1186288078
#>  [37] 2194374294 1179004039 1550151186  690514844  665066784 1457728244
#>  [43] 1340416729 1005633561  988219530 1163804357 2019609428 1810365923
#>  [49]  944348527 1350014516 1685059736 1068120639 1691385005 2082034143
#>  [55] 1447025244  943796075 2045470574 1420873777  707648814  653349704
#>  [61] 1471057561 1436128964 1550970115 1186032312  788508058 1265459073
#>  [67] 1829451696 1447903974  918204712 1312725482 1043733633  961860879
#>  [73]  781909574 1046090580  986760532  917758923  601335294 1321974824
#>  [79] 2438120829  833576485 1210382282 1738664778 1228776807 1648541762
#>  [85] 1400697543  995179656 1678005426 2072031752 1228366621  519232890
#>  [91] 1785013769  808690576 1978885855 2439935278 1264198838 2289052992
#>  [97] 2181566551 2450830549  430798470 2166454052
Created on 2021-10-12 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

Edit: To calculate area within groups in your data

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)

# I've loaded the data in your question as `df`
#
# I'll show how to calculate total areas for your group NAME,
# like you say in your question, but since there's only one
# unique value in your example data, I'll also make a dummy
# grouping variable to show the difference:

# Define dummy groups
df$id <- c(1,1,2,2,3)

# First, calculate the area of each polygon in your multipolygon
df$area <- st_area(df)

# Group by NAME and calculate a total area for each group.
# We expect this to return one area value, because there is only one group.

df %>% group_by(NAME) %>% summarize(st_union(geometry), area_NAME = sum(area))
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -8.667223 ymin: 26.5 xmax: -7.293025 ymax: 27.19647
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   NAME                                           `st_union(geometry)`  area_NAME
#>   <chr>                                                 <POLYGON [°]>      [m^2]
#> 1 Mauritania ((-7.5 26.62099, -7.693611 26.73416, -7.711945 26.74389~     5.59e9

# Now group by the dummy variable and calculate a total area for each group.
# In this case, we have three groups (1,2,3), so we expect three area values.

df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize(st_union(geometry), area_id = sum(area))
#> Simple feature collection with 3 features and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: GEOMETRY
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -8.667223 ymin: 26.5 xmax: -7.293025 ymax: 27.19647
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>      id                                           `st_union(geometry)`   area_id
#>   <dbl>                                                 <GEOMETRY [°]>     [m^2]
#> 1     1 MULTIPOLYGON (((-8.204445 27.0275, -8.5 27.19647, -8.5 27, -8~    1.30e9
#> 2     2 POLYGON ((-7.693611 26.73416, -7.711945 26.74389, -8 26.91053~    4.15e9
#> 3     3 POLYGON ((-7.5 26.62099, -7.5 26.5, -7.293025 26.5, -7.5 26.6~    1.39e8
Created on 2021-10-12 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

Edit2: Merge grouped data to original data

```
> df2 <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize(st_union(geometry), area_id = sum(area))

> merge(df, st_drop_geometry(df2), by = "id", all.x = TRUE)
Simple feature collection with 5 features and 4 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -8.667223 ymin: 26.5 xmax: -7.293025 ymax: 27.19647
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
  id       NAME             area          area_id
1  1 Mauritania  371871356 [m^2] 1295023668 [m^2]
2  1 Mauritania  923152312 [m^2] 1295023668 [m^2]
3  2 Mauritania 2683469487 [m^2] 4153042391 [m^2]
4  2 Mauritania 1469572903 [m^2] 4153042391 [m^2]
5  3 Mauritania  138546017 [m^2]  138546017 [m^2]
                        geometry
1 MULTIPOLYGON (((-8.155398 2...
2 MULTIPOLYGON (((-8.5 26.5, ...
3 MULTIPOLYGON (((-8 26.91053...
4 MULTIPOLYGON (((-7.5 26.620...
5 MULTIPOLYGON (((-7.293025 2...
```

Comment: I don't think I was clear enough. Sorry. For example, I want to know the surface area of each country in my NAME variable.

Comment: No worries. Are your data structured similar to `nc`, where each country is a row in your dataset? It is hard to know what advice to give without seeing the data. Are you able to share your data (or example data) in your question with `dput()`?  See this answer about grouping by some field in your data and calculating area by each group https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59330611/grouping-by-with-multipolygon-geometry-with-sf-using-r.

Comment: I edited the post with the dput function. And yes, I did as you said but not with st_read because I got an error (`dsn` must point to a source, not an empty string). So, I opened with read_sf.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how you can calculate total areas for groups of polygons. Let me know if anything is not clear. Thanks!

Comment: Ho Skaqqs, I owe you a coffee ! Thank you very much. But I stil have some questions. I converted the results in square kms (PRIO$area <- st_area((PRIO)/1000000)).  But R write in the cell that is m^2. Do you know why?

Comment: You're very welcome. Glad you figured it out! More questions are great; no worrie. Yes, units are stored as an attribute in `PRIO$area`, and when you change the units manually (technically you aren't changing the units, just dividing by 1000000), the sf object has no way of knowing to update the attributes. See this discussion (https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/291) and recommendation from the package author `units::set_units(x, km^2)`

Comment: Ok will do that! Second question: How can I append in a efficient way the results of the sum area to the PRIO dataframe? For example besides the column NAME I would like to have the column Total square km. And for the same country the value to repeat for each row. If Mauritania appears 3 times, to have the total km2, 3 times as well. It will ease me for some statistics in excel.

Comment: Sure. This sounds like a simple left-join. You can use `merge()`, just drop the geometry from `y=` first. I added another edit to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Last question:  I don't really get what `df$area <- st_area(df)` does exactly? You say "each polygon" but there is several polygon in the dataframe (AEZ, Country,) within the "gid" cell format.  In my context, it calculated the share of the AEZ within the country boundaries.

Comment: I'm not sure what "gid" cell format is. `df$area <- st_area(df)` calculates the area of each row in your data, which in `sf`, corresponds to a different spatial feature. To visualize, you can plot each feature independently `plot(df[1,"geometry"];plot(df[2,"geometry"];plot(df[3,"geometry"]`... and so on. Does that help?

Comment: Since I am here people are often rude or arrogant... and it's really frustrating sometimes to feel free to ask. In the name of science, a huge thank you for your professionalism and help! :)

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck

Comment: Hi @Skaqqs, sorry to disturb you again. I encountered a little issue with my results and I can't figure out how to interpret it. Would you mind to discuss this by email?

Comment: Sure, what's your email?